# How to hide other series when clicking on legend on highcarts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with multiple data series. How do I change it so that when I click on the legend it hides all other data points and only shows the data series I clicked on?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` from the `legendItemClick` event callback function to prevent the default legend behaviour and use `hide` and `show` methods on the relevant series.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    this.chart.series.forEach(s => {
                        s !== this ? s.hide() : s.show()
                    }, this);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tzLbxr20/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#show

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#hide